# Is it still possible to programme in LISP 1/1.5?

Tags: lisp

All of the resources online I find are for Common Lisp, even when I try to search specifically for original LISP resources.  I suspect that Common is probably a lot easier, but I thought it might be fun to try Lisp out from the beginning of it's history as a language.

Comment: It might be.  You would need an IBM 704 emulator, and there [appears to be one](https://github.com/rhobbie/Sim704).  You would also need to find a suitable machine-readable listing for a very early Lisp: I don't know of one.  If you want to be less archaic there is [LISPF4](https://github.com/blakemcbride/LISPF4) which is an early InterLisp.  There are at least a couple of [Standard Lisps](http://www.reduce-algebra.com/versions.php) around and people no doubt run things like MACLISP.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed comment @tfb.  I think this would be a good answer, if you'd like to add it down there.

Comment: I found a much better answer, and actually ran it, it is amazingly easy it turns out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and it's easy in fact.  [This person](http://web.sonoma.edu/users/l/luvisi/) has a tarball which lets you run Lisp 1.5 on the [SIMH](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/) emulator for the IBM 7094, which must have, I think, been the system Lisp 1.5 was ported to from the 704 (the 7094 is a transistor machine, the 704 was valve (tube)). [Here](https://www.slideshare.net/normanrichards/lisp-15) is a link to the slides from a talk given by Norman Richards at the March 2015 Clojure meetup where he must have demonstrated all this working.

### Example

I did this on a scratch Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

1. Get SIMH, with `aptitude install simh` or whatever you are using.
2. Get the above tarball and unpack it.
3. unpack the `utils-1.1.8.tar.gz` tarball inside it and build `txt2bcd`;
4. put `txt2bcd` somewhere in your `PATH`;
5. profit.

The tarball includes a factorial program, inevitably, and here's a transcript of it running:

```
ts$ i7094 lisptape.ini factorial.txt

IBM 7094 simulator V3.8-1
MTA: unit is read only
MTA: unit is read only
LPT: creating new file

HALT instruction, PC: 10524 (TRA 10523)
Goodbye
ts$ cat sys.log
             TEST  FACTORIAL



  THE TIME ( 0/ 0  000.0) HAS COME, THE WALRUS SAID, TO TALK OF MANY THI
NGS .....   -LEWIS CARROLL-
 EVALQUOTE OPERATOR AS OF 1 MARCH 1961.    INPUT LISTS NOW BEING READ.


  THE TIME ( 0/ 0  000.0) HAS COME, THE WALRUS SAID, TO TALK OF MANY THI
NGS .....   -LEWIS CARROLL-
  FUNCTION   EVALQUOTE   HAS BEEN ENTERED, ARGUMENTS..
 DEFINE

 (((FACTORIAL (LAMBDA (X) (COND ((EQUAL X 0) 1) (T (TIMES X (FACTORIAL (
SUB1 X)))))))))

 END OF EVALQUOTE, VALUE IS ..
 *TRUE*

  FUNCTION   EVALQUOTE   HAS BEEN ENTERED, ARGUMENTS..
 FACTORIAL

 (10)


 END OF EVALQUOTE, VALUE IS ..
 3628800



  THE TIME ( 0/ 0  000.0) HAS COME, THE WALRUS SAID, TO TALK OF MANY THI
NGS .....   -LEWIS CARROLL-
 END OF EVALQUOTE OPERATOR
             FIN      END OF LISP RUN
```

So it's that easy: I was amazed, having spent much longer than this trying to get MACLISP to run.  I think later systems are harder because they assume terminal types and so on as there is more interactivity.

### Some other links

Some other links which might be useful (some from my original comment):

- [a listing of Lisp 1.5 for (I presume) the IBM 7094)](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_stanfordliMar65_30065027/mode/1up);
- [an IBM 704 emulator for Windows](https://github.com/rhobbie/Sim704) if you wanted to go even further back;
- The [SIMH software kits list](http://simh.trailing-edge.com/software.html) lists Lisp for the PDP-1, which is what is described [here](http://s3data.computerhistory.org/pdp-1/DEC.pdp_1.1964.102650371.pdf) and which is also very early.